# How can I center an opt-in form that doesn't budge at all?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, responsive-design

If you go to https://dev.evolutionaryeducation.org and scroll down to the footer, there is a simple opt-in form that I can't seem to center no matter what I try and who I ask for help. No other developer I know has been able to figure it out, the theme developer is no help, the plugin developer is unresponsive, and I can't get it to work no matter I try based on Chrome Dev Tools. My client keeps asking about this and wants this form centered.

Please help.

[image: the form that needs centering]

Answer (score 0):

i inspect the element and check the code of css i made some changes on the css here

```
.mc4wp-form p > input {
    float: none;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

you can overwrite this by adding in @media query in your css check the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I tried something like that before and then this happens on desktop...  https://dev.evolutionaryeducation.org/

this is why I've been stuck on this issue for awhile. The plugin creates one form. I'm trying to get my client to upgrade to a premium plugin for it

Comment: dear you add in desktop version add in media query for mobile devices like this @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)
{.mc4wp-form p > input {
    float: none;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
} }

Comment: here is the list for the different device https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Almost working now! thank you so much! One small thing I can't fix now  
dev.evolutionaryeducation.org --- the button on that page and not the others seems misaligned still. how is that even possible?

Comment: try to give width: 100%; and check if you like this answer then please vote it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162278/discussion-between-aakanksh-patel-and-amar-patel).